# Azure long-term audit log

Tags: azure, audit-logging, azure-log-analytics, hipaa

We have a medical application that requires to store audit logs for 6 years (HIPAA requirement).

Looking at the new Azure Monitor service, it seems it will retain information for a maximum of 730 days (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/):

> How is data retention calculated? You can select a retention period
>   ranging from 30 to 730 days. The retention cost calculation is done on
>   a daily granularity based on the monthly price per GB being stored
>   beyond the 31 days of included retention.

Unfortunately this is a deal breaker, so we need to find another performance- and cost-effective Azure service for storing our audit logs. The audit log records need to have an API, be searchable by multiple criteria and support high-traffic.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think native audit logging\azure monitor offers something like that, so you are only left with various workarounds.

you could forward these logs to [event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs)\azure storage and process them into, say, cosmos db relatively easy with azure function. I think you can also setup [forwarding to a SIEM solution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/use-azure-monitor-to-integrate-with-siem-tools/). Generally there are a bunch of ways of solving this with using various other cloud resources.

Or you can consult [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/archive-activity-log) on how to archive those.